# What is this function declaration saying?

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

new to Javascript.

Was playing around with a controller for a calculator and came across this function definition. Its bizarre, and I'm hoping someone might be able to clarify this. Why is `number` repeated here?

```
function calculationCommission(monthlyRevenue: number): number {

//function does stuff

}
```

Comment: It's a TypeScript or Flow declaration that says the function takes a number and returns a number

Comment: Looks like [flow syntax](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/).  Flow and Typescript are both [static type checkers](https://ageek.dev/static-type-checkers) for Javascript code.  Both are similar, but have some small differences.  Typescript came out of microsoft, whereas flow came out of facebook.  In both cases, the typescript or flow code needs to be compiled to javascript during a build process.

Answer (score 0):

First number is type of argument of function that will receive and second one is type of function return.
In this situation both are number